# Differentiate active call is cellular call or voip call

Tags: ios, objective-c, voip, ctcallcenter

We are building voip based application and we have one scenario where we have to identify whether active call is voip call or cellular call(cs call). Before iOS10 and before callkit we used to check through CTCallCenter like below code snap.

```
- (BOOL)nativeCallPresent

   //This only works before callkit and ios 10,
   //If iOS is greater or equal 10 then it always return yes for CS and voip call both.

        CTCallCenter * callcenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];
        BOOL nativeCallPresent =  ([callcenter currentCalls] != nil);
        return nativeCallPresent;
}
```

I checked in apple callkit but did not find any way to check that active call is cellular call or voip call.

Can somebody from apple or developer community can help here?

Thanks.